# VBA select range to multiply with number but need to setup loop

Tags: vba, loops, range, multiplication

So I have the sub to select a range and to multiply the range with a certain number based on Input Boxes.
But I can't get it to loop through all the cells in the range.

I have the following sub which I have made out of separate other subs that I use:

```
Sub somesub()
Dim xVRg As Range
Set xVRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range you want to multiply:", "", Type:=8)
Dim Mnumber As Double
Mnumber = Application.InputBox("Enter number", "Multiply", Type:=1)

For Each xVRg In Selection
    If IsNumeric(xVRg) Then
    xVRg.Value = xVRg.Value * Mnumber
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

So this sub lets me select the range and let me input the number by which I want to have it multiplied.
I only can't get it looped through, so now only the cell that is selected will be changed and not the range that I have selected.

Do you have a tip to loop through the multiplier to ensure it loops through all the cells inside the range?

Comment: You might want to use `Dim ccell As Range` `For Each ccell in xVRG` instead of `For Each xVRG In Selection` as you've set your range xVRG to the selected range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. You select it only to `Set` it, it does not remain selected:

```
Sub somesub()
Dim xVRg As Range, cel As Range
Set xVRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range you want to multiply:", "", Type:=8)
Dim Mnumber As Double
Mnumber = Application.InputBox("Enter number", "Multiply", Type:=1)

For Each cel In xVRg
    If IsNumeric(cel) Then
    cel.Value = cel.Value * Mnumber
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

A faster version, using an array and processing only in memory, dropping the result a once, at the code end, will be the next one:

```
Sub somesubArray()
  Dim xVRg As Range, cel As Range, arr, i As Long, j As Long
 Set xVRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range you want to multiply:", "", Type:=8)
 Dim Mnumber As Double
 Mnumber = Application.InputBox("Enter number", "Multiply", Type:=1)

 arr = xVRg.Value2
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, j)) Then
            arr(i, j) = arr(i, j) * Mnumber
        End If
    Next j
 Next i

 'drop back the processed array:
 xVRg.Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: I used the second faster version and works great!

Comment: @Raaverok Placing the range in an array helps a lot, because all processing is done in memory (maximum speed) and not only that. Writhing one cell at a time, consumes more Excel resources and makes the code show. Dropping the processed array at once is the key of the efficiency. You can better see the difference if work on large ranges. Then, I would like to say that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. To also help somebody else searching for a similar issue...